# Create link to create Outlook events from Excel

Tags: excel, calendar, outlook, icalendar, vba

I have an Excel list with planned system change-events. The list has a change-no (A), impacted area (B), summary (C), description (D), scheduled start (E) and schedulend end (F).

Now, I want in column G a link, which generates an Outlook event for the current row using the values which are named above (A || C = Calendar Event-Name, B = Event Location, ....)

Does anybody have an idea if it is prossible to create a eventy by link (like mailto: makes a e-Mail)?

Thank you all,
Quast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code with changing the refrence in the sheet range as well concatenate the subject if needed....and this code will display the invite, if need to send automatically then change `".Display"` with `".Send"`

```
Sub SendbulkInvite()
On Error GoTo Err
Dim objemail As Outlook.Application
Dim obj1 As Object

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("startdatetime").Value < Sheets("Sheet1").Range("EndTime").Value Then
    MsgBox "Time range is not valid...", vbInformation, "Missing Info..."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set objemail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


            Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
            Range("Recipients").Activate
        For Each rec In Range("Recipients")
            If WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(rec)) <> "" Then

                Set obj1 = objemail.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

                With obj1
                    .Subject = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Subject").Value
                    .Location = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Location").Value
                    .Start = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("startdatetime").Value
                    .End = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("EndTime").Value
                    '.Duration = 120
                    .recipients.Add rec 'receipients name
                    .recipients.ResolveAll
                    .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
                    .AllDayEvent = "False"
                    .BusyStatus = "2"
                    '.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
                    .ReminderSet = True
                    .Body = Body
                    .Save
                    .Display
                End With
            End If
        Next


processend:
Exit Sub

Err:
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    Resume processend
End If
End Sub
```